# windows-8 on machine with AMD graphic card

Tags: windows-8

I have installed windows 8 on my HP laptop with AMD6770M  graphic card but driver is not being supported by it.How can I resolve it?

Comment: When you say not supported, do you mean you are warned that the hardware is not supported, or do you mean that something is going wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You need to either wait or accept the penalties that come with using unsupported hardware.

Have you tried the [beta driver](http://support.amd.com/us/kbarticles/Pages/AMDCatalyst1211betadriver.aspx)?

Are you using the dual graphics mode, with both Intel and AMD graphics hardware?

Comment: Also, have you tried going to HP's site and looking up your system and seeing if they have an official driver?

Comment: yes I have looked on official web site of HP.They have not given any driver update yet.Waiting for updates in future

Comment: What, does 12.10 not work? http://support.amd.com/us/gpudownload/windows/Pages/radeonaiw_win8-64.aspx I've been on Windows 8 since it released on MSDN (End of August for me specifically) and my AMD 7770 runs like a champ.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably looking for an **Intel+AMD Switchable Graphics driver**.

In that case, you may wish to read: [Win 8 AMD Switchable Graphics FAQ: (by Intel/AMD 3000 + 6770M owner)](http://www.eightforums.com/graphic-cards/7088-win-8-amd-switchable-graphics-faq-intel-amd-3000-6770m-owner.html)